# Why does my model deform so badly when I'm trying to animate it?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

So I have this Zbrush model that I made. It has separate parts for clothes, hair, eyes etc.
When I'm animating it, it deforms really weirdly and when I'm using it in a cloth simulation it gets some more weird deformations that I cant even explain.

I know some of the deformations can be solved through weight painting, but some parts apart from the body seems like "splitting or doubling" itself when I'm trying to move them in pose mode. No idea if the problem is in the model, some settings or just the weight paint, which I don't think in this case it is.

The default setup
[image: the default setup]

Cloth deforming when cloth simulation on.
[image: cloth deforming when cloth simulation on.]

The cloth seems to split or double itself when I rise the leg.
[image: model thigh cloth seems to split or double itself when i rise the leg]

More deformation errors
[image: some more deformations]

Comment: Hi, please add some screenshots to your question and/or upload your blend file to http://pasteall.org/ for people to look at.

Comment: yeah just added, (forgot)

Comment: it looks like you have a lot of duplicate topology. Edit your mesh, select all vertices with A, W for specials menu and remove double. Then you should re-parent your armature if it's not enough.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answer, was thinking about some duplicate typo but A, W gets me to specials menu but it only has 2 options something about restrict render. In the object mode and object data i have double sided unchecked, dont help thought. Dont know if thats the same thing you mean or not.

Comment: also remove or disable mirror modifier too if any to check undesired mirrored halves.

Comment: use it in Edit mode (tab to switch edit/object modes) with mesh selected (not armature)

Answer (score 1):

For a leg :

You have the leg itself, and a cloth, and the thickness of the cloth. Your problem lies in the inside part of the cloth that is not well vertex-weighted, and then not following the bone's movement.

cloth thickness

[image]

Cloth partially deformed

[image]

vertex weight of the cloth (1 bone selected)

[image]

What I suggest : Delete non-visible vertices (leg hidden by cloth, inside of cloth). As they won't be needed for render anyway, they're useless.

What you can do if you need to keep everything like that : Paint vertex weights (in weight paint mode) or at least assign the parts that need to move to the good vertex group

Weight paint mode

[image]

manually assign vertices to a vertex group

[image]

Comment: For more acurate answer, details and screenshots, send .blend

Comment: well thanks seemed like it would help but didnt have affect at all. I quess it could be that automatic weights doesnt correctly or even close add the weights to the all seperate parts, which i quess is kinda odd. Is there a way to make the cloth to "pin" on some areas of the model, or do you just have to make it precide weight painting.

Comment: I just noticed something, once i use automatic weights, somehow my clothes get thicker by double the amount they were before. but it only shows in the Pose Mode.

Comment: Seems weird but I can't do more without .blend :(

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34290

Comment: Okay well il look that up and try to fix it, and thanks for your time, appreciated :)

Comment: Good luck and try to have fun :)

Comment: For anyone reading this 5 years later...
If you don't want to delete hidden vertices (e.g. leg underneath cloth),
You can use the mask modifier to hide a vertex group
(Make sure to click the <--> double arrow thing).